# How does Thunderclap system with Facebook technically work to share every supports at the same time without asking any permission of audience?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-permissions

I'm aware of all the long lived token system with the Facebook API, but how does it work ? 
How is it possible to get the long lived token without store it on the server ? How can Thunderclap do to avoid the audience permission : you can't choose if you want to share your support on Facebook "only with friends" or "Me Only"or "Public", it goes directly Public on your wall ?

Many thanks.

Comment: They are probably using this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending